# Match balanced brackets after certain string

Tags: regex, perl

I am having trouble matching balanced brackets after a certain string"if". I know that I can match balanced brackets using

```
((?>[^()]|(?R))?\)
```

and that works just fine. However, when I add my string "if" before the this regular expression to be

```
if[ \t]*((?>[^()]|(?R))?\)
```

It only matches single balanced brackets after "if".

online demo: https://regex101.com/r/6lg0qi/3

Comment: I think you need [`if[ \t]*(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/R1w0ei/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?R)` means *recursing whole pattern* while you need to recurs chunk of it:

```
if[ \t]*(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/CqNzKp/1)